# Can't Run flutter app on ios after Amplify update 0.3.2

Tags: ios, flutter, aws-amplify

I get the following error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin (= 1.15.6, ~> 1.15.5)

  In Podfile:
    amplify_auth_cognito (from `.symlinks/plugins/amplify_auth_cognito/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin (= 1.19.0)

Specs satisfying the `AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin (= 1.15.6, ~> 1.15.5), AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin (= 1.19.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have set
platform :ios, '15.0'
in podfile

When I try to open in xcode and build the project I get the following error

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory

error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Answer (score 0):

from your root flutter project open the terminal and type

```
cd ios
```

and then run

```
pod install
```

if that doesn't work then run

```
pod deintegrate
```

and then

```
pod install
```

Comment: Pod install shows same error. I think you meant pod deintegrate. pod disintegrate is unknown command. Anyways after pod deintegrate running pod install gives same error.

Comment: can you please post the error / output